# What is "Unable to handle kernel paging request at 00000000313337000"

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, dereference, exploit

I wanted to work through this independent study http://security.cs.rpi.edu/~candej2/syllabus.pdf myself to pick up some basics on exploit writing and actually being able to write an exploit from scratch. So... I was looking at http://security.cs.rpi.edu/~candej2/kernel/trivial_sploit.c
and http://security.cs.rpi.edu/~candej2/kernel/trivial.c, and was trying to understand how it works.

I tried running it by doing

```
# insmod trivial.ko
$ ./exploit
```

The exploit got to

```
[+] mapped 0x31337000
```

And then then in my VM (I set kgdboc), I saw

```
BUG: Unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000000031337000
IP: [<0000000031337000>] 0x31337000
PGD 3a89e067 PUD 3aea2067 PMD 3b333067 PTE 31b57067
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda/dev
KGDB: Waiting for remote debugger
```

Why might this be the case?

Comment: Probably NX bit is set on the mmap'd page. Also, that exploit seems to have been written for a 32-bit kernel and you're executing it on a 64-bit kernel.

Comment: Do you know how I can check the NX bit? Is switching off the NX bit the same thing as setting PROT_EXEC? PROT_EXEC was set in the mmap call. I understand that the function `generate_shellcode(char *buf)` generates assembly with `eax` in it, but I think this page fault comes about before any of that assembly is executed. (I'll try a 32 bit VM to verify this) Thanks!

Comment: Tried it on a 32 bit system, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found out - it's SMEP. I can disable it by adding nosmep as a boot parameter